# Reduce database requests in local db

Tags: android, regex, database, realm, data-modeling

I have a list view in android where i have to check every time do display the List item or not
to **reduce** the requests what i did is saved the id in a single row like

> 1,2,10,

everything was working fine to **search** i just had to use

```
 String[] favs = fav.split(",");
    for (int index = 0; index <(favs.length); index++) {
        if(favs[index]==""){}else {
            wishlist.add(Integer.parseInt(favs[index].trim()));
        }

  if(clicklist.contains((int)temp.getId())) //like this
```

and to **remove** from db like, this

```
temp2.replaceAll(""+m1.getId()+",", "") // and save in the db
```

now issue is i have two more data field associated with id like

> 10|data1|data2,100|apple|dog,150|data12|data24

1. **Question 1** is this data model ok for small db
2. **Question 2** how to perform search and delete in new data set?

please help!

Comment: How is this question Realm related?

Comment: if there is a faster way in realm to check each list item in android?

Comment: Considering NOTHING in this question even resembles canonical Realm usage in any way and there is no RealmQuery in the question, I assume yes.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce how we can implement `where()` clause on realmResult here?

Comment: I cannot answer that question without knowledge of the data you are storing and your current RealmObjects

Comment: can you share any of you example code using `where()` clause on reamlResult i tried to find any example but i was not able to find but if you have please can you share thanks!

Comment: The official documentation is a good place to check https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#chaining-queries

Comment: @EpicPandaForce by this method i have to use query for every item in list view

Comment: Well you never really defined what you are trying to do either :D

Comment: I wasn't kidding when I said that you never defined your Realm schema, where Realm actually comes into play in this code, and what you are trying to accomplish exactly.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce get `realmResults` go through the results and on that basis display row(ListView item) or not without calling db again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a db is a proper choice here, i suggest you to take a look to the recently released [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html), an Android component made by Google developers to support data persistence more easily.

You should of course know the basis of sql language.

In your case you should annotate your data class with @Entity annotation:

```
@Entity
public class DataModel {
@PrimaryKey
private int uid;

@ColumnInfo(name = "animal")
private String animal;

@ColumnInfo(name = "fruit")
private String fruit;

// Getters and setters are ignored for brevity,
// but they're required for Room to work.
}
```

And then, to answer your question about CRUD operations,  define a Dao:

```
@Dao
public interface UserDao {

@Query("SELECT * FROM DataModel")
List<DataModel> getAll();

@Insert
void insertAll(DataModel... dataModels);

@Delete
void delete(DataModel dataModel);
}
```